# With CodeIgniter, how would you create a user account and then send an email with form values?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using CodeIgniter, I am using a form to create a user. The user does get created in the database. In my users model, I am manipulating the value of verification_hash before it gets inserted into the DB:

```
public function set_user(){

    $data = array(
        'temporary_email'   => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password'          => $this->input->post('password'),
        'verification_hash' => sha1(mt_rand(1000, 9999999))
    );

    $this->db->set('created', 'NOW()', FALSE);

    return $this->db->insert('users', $data);
}
```

Then, I want to be able to send an email using the Email class. I need to be able to use the new value of 'verification_hash' in my email.

If there is a better way to do this, I'm all ears, I'm still learning CI. Thanks, Jason

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I think this is better idea which i am proposing first when user registers send a default password to them and when they login first time force them to reset password and then reset your has variable............

Answer (score 1):

You could just return the the `$data` array and then your controller code will be something like

```
public function foo()
{
 if($this->input->post('user'))
 {
    //Validation rules

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $user = $this->user_model->set_user();
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('email@email.com', 'Name');
        $this->email->to($user['temporary_email']);

        $this->email->subject('Welcome');
        $this->email->message($user['verification_hash']);

        $this->email->send();

    } else {
        //Reloads Same form with errors
    }
 }
}
```

But im not shure why you create a user for temporary data like that i would rather have a like a url table and then have the `unique_hash/url | user_id | status`  and then get them to full in most important data and then send the email and then for them to proceed to do the more important stuff on the site the **hash_status** must be set to used